# How to find minimum arguments in a triple for loop with changing dimension

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, min

I'm new at programming so, I had troubles even with simple things;
I am trying to get 3 vectors`g1vec & a1vec & z1vec` out of a triple `for` loop below, I have a `Xvec` which has 120 data in it, what I want is for every `x in Xvec` trying 90 `A` values and at every `A` there will be `Zs` up to that A (Zs are float at first then by comparing the ceil and floor I will take the one which gives me minimum) then with these values find the best `A`,`Zs` couple that minimizes my function `gibbs` for 120 `Xvec` values.
After days of trials, I could write the code below, but the code works so slow and I think there should be *direct* method to find these `A` and `Zs` argument, actually I'm not even sure that with this code I am getting the results I need. Any advice is highly appreciated

```
    for x in Xvec:          
        for A in range(1,91):  
            for Zs in (np.arange(1, A+1 , 0.1 , dtype=float)):

                g = gibbs(x,A,Zs)
                g1 = np.append(g1,g)

            min_pos, minofg = g1.argmin() , g1.min()

            Zpos = 1+(0.1)*min_pos
            Zceil = np.ceil(Zpos)     
            Zfloor = np.floor(Zpos)   

            gc = gibbs(x,A,Zceil)        
            gf = gibbs(x,A,Zfloor)        

            k = min(gc,gf)
            if k == gc:   Z = Zceil
            else:   Z = Zfloor
            z1 = np.append(z1,Z)
            x1 = np.append(x1,x)
            a1 = np.append(a1,A)                                    

    for N in range(0,10711,90):
        a = min(g1[N:N+90])     
        g1vec = np.append(g1vec,a)
        b = g1[N:N+90].argmin()
        a1vec = np.append(a1vec,a1[N+b])
        z1vec = np.append(z1vec,z1[N+b])
```

So at the end I need to have 3 vectors one with a minimum possible values of a function `gibbs` at every x and the other 2 are the `A` and `Zs` values that gives that minimum value of the function.
After I could not find any other way I calculated all posibilities and then tried to seperate them in another for loop but it takes forever and I have lots of doubts that it actually even works.

Comment: what you mean with min(g1[N:N+90]) ? example:  [90:90+90].....

Comment: I think g1[0:90] gives me the elements of vector from g1[0] to g1[90] so since I couldn't find the minimum positions I tried to seek every 90 interval by hand and find the min at every 90 steps which I though would correspond to a specific value of `A`. I might be wrong though

Comment: I think g1[0:90] will give you the vector from g1[0] to g1[90], thats fine but in the code you asking for g1[90] to g1[90]:  "g1[N:N+90]"

Comment: I don't see how. I have N in some range and below, I have g1[N:N+90] so since it is not g1[N:N] it is impossible to have begining and end limit as you say? Am I missing something, 
lets say N is 270 then I'll have g1[270:270+90]=g1[270:360]  a vector of length 90. I don't see why this part is problematic

Comment: sry i did the indexing first